# python urllib certificate verify failed

Tags: python, python-3.6, urllib3

I have the follwing script:

```
from currency_converter import CurrencyConverter

test = CurrencyConverter('http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref.zip')
```

I try to run it on machine with windows 10 and python 3.6.7 and always get this error:

```
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:847)>
```

Running it on other windows 10 machines with python 3.6 works fine. I tried it on this machine with python 3.7 and get the same error.  What could be wrong with the python installation ?

Comment: it is very mysterious. i had set brave as standard browser. after resetting the standard browser settings to ms edge. everything works fine. setting brave again as standard browser makes no difference the error doesnt show up any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it worked on MS Edge and not in Brave is because Brave doesn't have root ca added in trusted certificates. You need to add your `ROOT_CA` certificate in brave browser.